# Não estou conseguindo colocar meu texto no lado direito do site

Tags: html, css, float

[image: Estou com problemas para colocar o codigo aqui ent~]ao coloquei uma imagem,ele fica me dando erroa]

Estou com um problema ao tentar colocar meu texto no lado direito do site, o texto fica no lado esquerdo, quero deixar no lado direito da pagina

Comment: `.menua {
  text-align: right;
}` vai resolver seu problema, mas estou votando para fechar pq sua pergunta não está no padrão de qualidade do site. Tente coloca seu código em forma de texto e não em forma de imagem, isso facilita para alguém copiar seu código e te responder etc

Answer (score 0):

Coloque em seu css na classe .menua;

```
 .menua { display: inline-block; float: right;}
```

Comment: Float não é para alinhar texto a direita. Alinhamento de texto é com `text-align` não com `float`

Comment: Cara, tente testar o codico, veria que text-align nao moveu sequer o texto para direita, em nenhuma das classes.

Answer (score 0):

Em melhores praticas esta maneira de disponibilizar as tags não é muito recomendável, já que corresponde a um menu. Você deveria usar a tag UL e dentro de cada LI colocar seus links, tag A.
Isto se dá pelo fato de garantir uma estrutura compreensivel caso o css não seja carregado por algum motivo. A ideia é a estrutura ser compreensivel. Aconselho a usar Lista e formatar ela ao invés do link.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```